# How to customise "Unauthorized" error message from AWS Lambda authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have written a lambda authorizer function that calls two custom authorization services to validate the input token. So, from lambda authorizer, I want to return different possible messages for the status code 401. For example,

"INVALID credentials", "Missing Credentials", "Token Revoked".

In case of Allow or Deny, I can set variables in context object which in turn i can use in gateway response as "context.authorized.parameter_name".

But, In case of Unauthorized, is there any way of customising the error messages ?

Comment: any updates on this yet?